# Number of Integer solutions for this optimization problem

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

What is the number of integer solutions to the problem
$$\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}x_i = n$$ subject to $\forall_i\ \  x_i \ge 0 $

**note** This should hold for both cases $k < n$ and $k \ge n$

Comment: Is order of the $x_i$'s important?

Comment: @Dan, yes its important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is given by the formula $$CC_k^n = {n+k-1 \choose n}$$

Comment: so is this problem equivalent to distributing $n$ distinct balls into $k$ distinct boxes?

Comment: $n$ similar balls into $k$ distinct boxes